# Problem with installing GWT 2.1 on Eclipse 3.6

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, installation

I downloaded GWT 2.1 and extracted it into this folder "G:\eclipse\dropins", and restarted Eclipse after that, but I can't see the GWT plugin in Eclipse.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you follow the recommended process?

http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html

I works perfectly ;)

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial? http://ukitech.blogspot.com/2009/11/updating-to-gwt-20-rc1.html
It's a bit old, but maybe helpful.